# How to use Jersey with Eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

My base need is to use the Jersey framework to develop very basic REST webservices.

I've read several tutorials regarding Jersey (JAX-RS framework) and writing webervices but so for I've not found an easy way to setup a development environment based on Eclipse Helios and Glassfish (Open Source Edition). When creating a Webservice in Eclipse, it seems to use JAX-WS, or when creating a Dynamic Web App, Eclipse reports a credentials error (I use admin/admin) or a wrong user name / password.

The tutorials I've found either use myEclipse, or Tomcat, or Maven. The later works pretty well but I wish I could avoid using the command line because creating the web.xml and other files like that one is really scary, and I'm not sure these files are supposed to be human-written. So I suppose (maybe I'm wrong) using a IDE will make things easier.

What do guys use ? How do you generate these files ? Do you use Eclipse only for writting code or also use the deploy facilities?

Any pointers are appreciated !

Thank you

SCO

Comment: I actually solved this by adding the JAX-RS support for the runtime. I also activated security from within the Glassfish Admin Console, but not sure it helped (just telling it here just in case).

Thank for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You DO need to modify web.xml whenever it's needed. Especially with JAX-RS, you will have to define your servlet in web.xml.

I recommand you to use Maven. There are plenty of exemple in the web to do so. Good luck, JAX-RS is really great ! Maven is also nice.

Answer (score 0):

I also use eclipse for creating and consuming web service based applications. In addition to WTP, I also use Axis plugins to make things easier (through wizards, highlighting as well as for schema verification).
The bottomline is to find the plugins that suit you the best

Comment: OMG, still another piece of software ! ;) Please tell me when this will stop ! Sooo many tools, it's amazing. I don't want to use SOAP/JAX-WS, it looks like Axis is SOAP oriented ?

Comment: Axis also supports REST APIs as WSDL 2.0 standard has http binding support it. But it doesn't supports the jersey implementation in full, as you indicated.